# How to stop speech in automator action

Tags: applescript, automator, text-to-speech, speech

I can make an Applescript within automator so it reads text at N speed:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  repeat with thisText in input
      say thisText speaking rate 400
  end repeat
end run
```

However, is there a way to stop the speech at any given point? There is the option of clicking the cogwheel at the top menu bar, but I was looking for a shortcut-able way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few different solutions:

- This applescript immediately kills all speech that is running on your computer:

> ```
> do shell script "killall com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd"
> ```

- Alternatively, you could have a single script that checks to see if the speech is running and will kill that particular speech, (basically simulates the shortcut for alt-esc, BUT you can add the rate function to the script). I found a script online a while back that does this. Here's the [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272573/applescript-is-it-possible-to-check-if-speech-is-currently-running). I also made my own version that changes the rate (at the bottom of the post). The rate control is where it says [[rate 800]]. This script copies text to the clipboard and adds '[[rate 800]]' which apple tts voices interpret as a command to change to that rate. The clipboard is read at the modified speed. You can adjust up to like 1000 or something.
- However, if you really just want to make your mac's default text to speech rate faster (which is what I suspect you are using this script for), I highly recommend you just change the default rate using a little hack I came up with a while back (It allows you to go up to 720 WPM). I have a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-tWT7SOq-4) that describes it all. Basically, it changes the default rate using a script.

> ```
> use AppleScript version "2.4"
> use scripting additions
> use framework "Foundation"
> use framework "AppKit"
> property this_say_Pid : missing value -- the persistent property
>
> if this_say_Pid is not missing value then -- check the pid of all 'say' commands, if exists then quit the unix process
>   set allSayPid to {}
>   try
>       set allSayPid to words of (do shell script "pgrep -x 'say'")
>   end try
>   if this_say_Pid is in allSayPid then -- the PID = an item in the list
>       do shell script "/bin/kill " & this_say_Pid -- quit this process to stop the speech
>       error number -128 -- quits the AppleScript
>   end if
> end if
>
> -- Back up original clipboard contents:
> set savedClipboard to my fetchStorableClipboard()
>
> -- Copy selected text to clipboard:
> tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {command down}
>
> delay 0.1
>
> tell application "System Events"
>
>   set varClip to "[[rate 800]]" & (the clipboard)
>   delay 0.1
>   set the clipboard to varClip
>
> end tell
>
>
> delay 0.1 -- Without this, the clipboard may have stale data.
>
> -- Speak the clipboard:
> --  pbpaste = the contents of the clipboard , this run the commands without waiting, and get the PID of the 'say' command 
> set this_say_Pid to do shell script "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 pbpaste -Prefer txt | say > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"
>
> -- Restore original clipboard:
> my putOnClipboard:savedClipboard
>
> on fetchStorableClipboard()
>   set aMutableArray to current application's NSMutableArray's array() -- used to store contents
>   -- get the pasteboard and then its pasteboard items
>   set thePasteboard to current application's NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
>   -- loop through pasteboard items
>   repeat with anItem in thePasteboard's pasteboardItems()
>       -- make a new pasteboard item to store existing item's stuff
>       set newPBItem to current application's NSPasteboardItem's alloc()'s init()
>       -- get the types of data stored on the pasteboard item
>       set theTypes to anItem's types()
>       -- for each type, get the corresponding data and store it all in the new pasteboard item
>       repeat with aType in theTypes
>           set theData to (anItem's dataForType:aType)'s mutableCopy()
>           if theData is not missing value then
>               (newPBItem's setData:theData forType:aType)
>           end if
>       end repeat
>       -- add new pasteboard item to array
>       (aMutableArray's addObject:newPBItem)
>   end repeat
>   return aMutableArray
> end fetchStorableClipboard
>
>
> on putOnClipboard:theArray
>   -- get pasteboard
>   set thePasteboard to current application's NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
>   -- clear it, then write new contents
>   thePasteboard's clearContents()
>   thePasteboard's writeObjects:theArray
> end putOnClipboard:
> ```

Comment: The first code does what I aimed to do, so thanks! The other ideas are great, also implemented them, so thanks! PS: I don't know how to mark this answer as the response.

Comment: Awesome! Very happy to help. As for your voting, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers